# Как часто надо вызывать сборщик мусора?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Как часто надо вызывать сбощик мусора?
System.gc()? Имею ввиду после каких действий?

Comment: В правильно написанной программе, никогда. Он вызывается сам. А в неправильно написанной, вызов ничего не даст. И кстати вызов `System.gc()` в принципе ничего не гарантирует.

Comment: Ага, он вызвается сам да, но когда уже некуда резервировать память.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

System.gc() - не вызывает сборщик мусора, а просто дает рекомендацию системе выполнить сборку.

Более того, поведение сборщика мусора сильно зависит от [стратегий](http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=14)

Мой же ответ на вопрос: "как часто?" - не трогайте этот метод. Вспомните про него после того, как изучите хорошо принипы работы виртуальной машины и сборщика мусора, не раньше. На данном же этапе вы не сможете воспользоваться этим знанием с пользой.

Рекомендую вместо этого разобраться с причинами которые приводят к утечкам.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, буду проверять свои классы на утечки