# Утечка памяти при многократном запуске потока

Tags: java, многопоточность, утечка-памяти

Доброго (CurrentTime) ,Столкнулся со странностью при многократном создании потока и по завершению исполнения озу не освобождается, можете рассказать что тут происходит, прошу извинений за вопрос тк новичок?

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100000) {
      TestThread test = new TestThread();
      test.start();
      i++;
    }

    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(8000);

  }

}
```

Класс TestThread

```
public class TestThread extends Thread {

   public void run() {

    // Пустой

  }

}
```

Comment: Как вы выяснили что ОЗУ не освобождается? С какими параметрами запускается приложение? Я полагаю, что происходит так: предположим, что программа стартует с -Xms64M -Xmx512M, тогда при старте программа будет есть 64 мегабайта памяти, при накапливании объектов куча будет расти, и её размер может дорасти до 512 мегабайт, при этом это будет не суммарный размер созданных объектов, а размер кучи, она не обязательно должна быть вся занята, но при этом операционная система считает, что все 512 мегабайт выделены JVM, что в общем-то говоря правда.

Comment: @iksuy Спасибо,большое кажется понял те размер кучи не уменьшается после удаления объектов так?

Comment: Он уменьшается, но не сразу, а через какое-то время, но на это не стоит расчитывать.

Comment: Кроме того, вызов System.gc(); не гарантирует ничего

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Несколько возможных причин для такого поведения:

1. Потоки не завершились на момент вызова `System.gc`.

Потоки, хоть они ничего и не делают, требуют выделения ресурсов для запуска. Вы запускаете один за другим 100000 потоков, а затем вызываете сразу `gc` не дожидаясь их завершения. Часть потоков может быть не завершена на этот момент. Дождаться завершения работы потока можно с помощью [`Thread.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

2. Вызов `System.gc` не обязательно запускает сборщик мусора.

Из документации к [`System.gc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()):

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. ...
>
> Вызов метода предлагает виртуальной машине Java приложить усилия для обработки неиспользуемых объектов, чтобы сделать память, которую они занимают, доступной для быстрого повторного использования. ....

В общем, это рекомендация, которая не гарантирует сборку мусора. Сборка мусора произойдет когда виртуальная машина посчитает нужным. Можете еще почитать ответ на вопрос: «[Как часто надо вызывать сборщик мусора?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)»

3. Сборка мусора не обязательно освобождает память для ОС.

Даже если сборка мусора запустится, нет никакой гарантии, что освобожденная память будет возвращена ОС для использования в других процессах.

Освобождение памяти и выделение ее заново — ресурсоемкие задачи, которые могут оказать влияние на производительность клиентского (Вашего) кода. Поэтому разработчики JVM предусматривают сложные алгоритмы сборки мусора с минимальным влиянием на исполнение. В зависимости от настроек памяти JVM и используемого сборщика мусора память может быть сохранена для повторного использования Java (на очистку вообще не тратятся ресурсы) либо возвращена частично до определенного процентного порога (перераспределение памяти происходит в ограниченных масштабах).

Подробнее о разных сборщиках мусора смотрите в документации к используемой Вами версии JVM. Можете также ознакомиться с обзорными статьями по теме:

- Статьи на сайте Oracle: [Java HotSpot Garbage Collection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-jsp-140228.html);
- [Теория и практика Java: Сборка мусора в HotSpot JVM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp11253/);
- серия статей «[Дюк, вынеси мусор!](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269621/)» на Хабре.